# What are the statistics of the discrete Fourier transform of a Bernoilli process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis, infinite-product

## The problem

I would like to understand the statistics of the discrete Fourier transform of a sequence of uncorrelated events $\{x_n\}$ each of which takes the value $\pm1$ with probability $1/2$.
In other words, the probability distribution of the $n^\text{th}$ event is

$$P_{x_n}(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left( \delta(x - 1) + \delta(x + 1) \right) \, . $$

Note that the distribution does not depend on $n$.
This stochastic process is called a Bernoilli process.
The discrete Fourier transform of the sequence is

$$X_k \equiv \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_n e^{-i 2 \pi n k / N} \, .$$

What are the statistics of $X_k$?$^{[a]}$

## My attempt

The $x_n$ values are random, so $X_k$ is also random; we want to analyze its statistics.
We simplify the problem by first considering only the real part of $X_k$,

$$\Re X_k = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_n \cos(2 \pi n k / N) \, . $$

Let $\xi_n \equiv x_n \cos(2\pi n k / N)$ so that

$$\Re X_k = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \xi_n \, .$$

The probability distribution of a sum of random variables is equal to the convolution of the distributions of the variables being summed, so

$$P_{\Re X_k} = \bigotimes_{n=0}^{N-1} P_{\xi_n} \tag{1}$$

where $\otimes$ means convolution and $P_{\xi_n}$ is the probability distribution of $\xi_n$ which is

\begin{align}
P_{\xi_n}(\xi)
&= \frac{1}{2 \cos(2 \pi n k / N)}
\left(
\delta \left( \frac{\xi}{\cos(2\pi n k / N)} - 1 \right) + 
\delta \left( \frac{\xi}{\cos(2\pi n k / N)} + 1 \right)
\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2 \cos(2 \pi n k / N)}
\left(
\delta \left( \xi - \cos(2\pi n k / N) \right) + 
\delta \left( \xi + \cos(2\pi n k / N) \right)
\right) \, .
\end{align}

Equation $(1)$ is difficult because it involves a convolution.
We simplify by Fourier transforming because the Fourier transform of a convolution is the product of the Fourier transforms of the things being convolved.
This turns Eq. $(1)$ into

$$\mathcal{F}(P_{\Re X_k})(\nu) = \prod_{n=0}^{N-1}
\left( \frac{1}{2 \cos(2\pi n k / N)}\right)
\left(
e^{-i 2 \pi \nu \cos(2 \pi n k / N)} + e^{i 2 \pi \nu \cos(2 \pi n k / N)}
\right)
\, .
$$

How can we proceed?
In principle I'd like to evaluate the product and then inverse Fourier transform to arrive at the distribution for $\Re X_k$.
This strategy works quite easily in the case that $x_n$ is Gaussian distributed (the product is trivial in that case) but here we've run into a product which, so far, I do not know how to evaluate.

$[a]$: Because the events are independent I'm reasonably sure that the spectral density ought to be independent of frequency, but I'd like to see the full statistics of $X_k$.